# Query Inner Join with two ID in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm saving 2 id inside the same table and then I do an inner to get the name but I can get only one name. How would I get the two names

table1

```
 ------------------------
|id|name       |xxx     | 
|--|-----------|--------|  
|1 |name1      |xxx1    | 
|2 |name2      |xxx2    | 
|3 |name3      |xxx3    |
|  |           |        | 
|--|-----------|--------|
```

table2

```
 --------------------------------------
|id|table1User |CLIENT  |table1Worker | 
|--|-----------|--------|-------------|
|5 |1          |xxx1    |2            |  
|6 |1          |xxx2    |2            |
|7 |3          |xxx3    |3            |
|--|-----------|--------|-------------|
```

here my query

```
     SELECT a.id, p.name, p.CLIENT, p.table1Worker
        FROM table2 as a INNER JOIN table1 as p ON p.id = a.table1User
```

with this query I get this result but I want in the `table1Worker` show the name

```
 --------------------------------------
|id|table1User |CLIENT  |table1Worker | 
|--|-----------|--------|-------------|
|5 |name1      |xxx1    |2            |  
|6 |name1      |xxx2    |2            |
|7 |name3      |xxx3    |3            |
|--|-----------|--------|-------------|
```

How should I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the table twice. This is one of the things aliases are for; an alias will let you distinguish two instances of the same table:

```
SELECT t2.id, t1user.name "table1User", t2.CLIENT, t1worder.name "table1Worker"
FROM table2 t2 
INNER JOIN table1 t1user ON t1user.id = t2.table1User
INNER JOIN table1 t1worker ON t1worker.id = t2.table1Worker
```